# How Ubuntu/Linux defines value to force check disks/partitions on boot?

Tags: 12.04, server, fsck

Yesterday I was a little bit scared when I saw this error message on a production server when connecting to ssh :

```
*** /dev/sda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
```

I thought there were errors on the system, but here is the result :

```
/dev/mapper/name--name1--vg-root : propre, 1460579/60497920 fichiers, 57725191/241971200 blocs
/dev/sda1 a été monté 30 fois sans avoir été vérifié, vérification forcée.
```

Everything seems fine.

- I would like to know where the value to check errors is defined (here seems to be 30) ? And how many times the volume was mounted after the last check ?
- I also would like to know why it's only on this server and not the others I have (there are configured almost identically except this one has logical volume) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dumpe2fs` command is the one to get this information for you, so long as you're using an `ext*` filesystem. Ubuntu tends to use ext4 as default. I tend to use it with the `-h` option, to only output the summary. This contains the most useful information.
To get the info you require, type:

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1
```

'Mount count', and 'Maximum mount count' are the fields you're looking for, but 'Check interval' also influences disk checks based on time. I've found that if you cancel a disk check 'Maximum mount count' changes to -1, so no disk checking will take place based on number of mounts.

To change the maximum mount count or interval, use the `tune2fs` command the `-c` option controls max mount count, an `-i` controls interval. `man tune2fs` contains more info about this command.